# Gnome library reader/writer lock implementation

Tags: locking, glib, gnome

The Gnome library provides a number of functions for read write locks, these are g_rw_lock_writer_lock () and g_rw_lock_reader_lock () [https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#g-rw-lock-writer-lock].

Is the implementation of these functions any close to what is described in this Wikipedia article [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock]. More specifically, in which category these functions belong a Read-preferring RW, Write-preferring RW or unspecified?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `GRWLock` implements a standard read/write lock as described in the Wikipedia article. It has unspecified priority rules.

On Unix systems, `GRWLock` is [actually implemented](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/da8f1c6ac34c0fb54f0e2cb4305c30c1f84e6812/glib/gthread-posix.c#L430) using the [`pthread_rwlock_*()` functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_rwlock_init.html). These also have unspecified priority rules, but this at least means you know it will behave the same as most other read/write lock implementations on your system.